# Purpose of using @Configuration annotation

Tags: spring, spring-annotations

I have created a spring mvc based application but I didn't use this @Configuration annotation. What is the purpose of using @Configuration annotation? By using this, what are we communicating to springMVC container?

Comment: that is alternative to XML configuration. Classes annotated with @Configuration can be loaded by spring container with **AnnotationConfigApplicationContext** . If you use XML based config, then you should use **ClassPathXmlApplicationContext** to initialize your spring application context.
Here is a pointer - http://www.theserverside.com/tip/How-the-Java-Config-Module-Pounced-on-Spring-30

Comment: thank you so much for the link - it was very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your application is using xml configuration rather than AnnotationConfig so it is not loaded to ApplicationContext at all.

@Configuration is used when ApplicationContext has been initialized and bean registration.

Answer (score 0):

@Configuration annotation is a core Spring annotation, and not Spring MVC. It is a core entry point to configuring Spring-based application using Java config instead of XML config.

Please, use Spring Documentation more often because it is a place where you will find answers to most of your questions. Like this one:

> Indicates that a class declares one or more Bean @Bean methods and may
>   be processed by the Spring container to generate bean definitions and
>   service requests for those beans at runtime